# Inequalities for the probability of union and intersection of events

Tags: probability, inequality

Prove that

1. $\min(1, P(A)+P(B))\ge P(A\cup B)$
2. $\min(P(A),P(B))\ge P(A\cap B)\ge \max(0,P(A)+P(B)-1)$

Where $A$ and $B$ are events.

I don't know how to prove them; Can you give me a hand please?, I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) $$p(A\cup B)=p(A)+p(B)-p(A\cap B)\leq p(A)+p(B)$$ and $$p(A\cup B)\leq 1$$
Then $$p(A\cup B)\leq\min\{p(A)+p(B), 1\}$$

2) $A\cap B\subset A$ and $A\cap B\subset B$. So, $$p(A\cap B)\leq p(A)$$ and $$p(A\cap B)\leq p(B).$$
Therefore $$p(A\cap B)\leq \max\{p(A),p(B)\}.$$
By definition, $p(A\cap B)\geq 0$. Moreover, 
$$1\geq p(A\cup B)=p(A)+p(B)-p(A\cap B)$$
and so
$$1\geq p(A)+p(B)-p(A\cap B)\implies p(A\cap B)\geq p(A)+p(B)-1.$$

Therefore $$\min\{p(A),p(B)\}\geq p(A\cap B)\geq \max\{0,p(A)+p(B)-1\}.$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Really appreciate it :D

Comment: Typo: $\max\{p(A),p(B)\}$ should be replaced by $\min\{p(A),p(B)\}$